# Automatic discovery of master by sentinel

Tags: python, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-py

A redis master can be discovered via sentinel using:

```
from redis.sentinel import Sentinel
sentinel = Sentinel([('127.0.0.1', 26379)])
master_server = sentinel.master_for('mymaster')
```

Now to write data to the master node :

```
master_server.setex(key, 120, value)
# do something
master_server.setex(key, 120, new_value)
```

Now, while `# do something`, if the `master_server` crashes, `sentinel` will promote a slave to master by voting. Hence, `master_server.setex(key, 120, new_value)` will throw a **MasterNotFoundError**.

A workaround is to *try-catch* this block; Is there a way such that master discovery is automatically handled by redis? Since placing *try-catch* everywhere in the code would make the code redundant and messy.

Answer (score 0):

Redis sentinel actually *does* have automatic rediscovery of master, as it uses the [SentinelConnectionPool](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/sentinel.py#L69). While it does have some issues—see my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180510/redis-py-sentinel-connectionerror-race-condition-during-failover)—it sounds like the issue here is that your redis setup isn't successfully electing a new master.

Do you have an odd number of sentinels with an appropriately set quorum?

https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Check out the redis sentinel page to make sure you aren't running into some of the common pitfalls.

Comment: I understand that a new master will be automatically discovered. My questions is, suppose if master_server is set to node_a...and node_a crashes midway...then do I always have to again set `master_server = sentinel.master_for('mymaster')` in a try-catch block

Comment: @greenlantern Did you find any better solution than try-catch-refresh-master?